# Safari CSS: Background Color Washed Out

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I have created a site which looks great in Chrome but in Safari the button's background color looks bleached (silver background with white text).  I saw someone say that it's because I am overwriting the bootstrap style.  Why would that cause this issue?  People have also suggested to avoid the "!important" qualifier.  Does that make sense on its face?

[image: Good Button]
[image: Not a good looking button]

The one on the left is how it should look.  The right one is what Safari displays.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code any answer is just a guess, my guess being that you are using some CSS property  that isn’t supported in Safari so the system is using its default values. Please add code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a type="button" class="btn-secondary" target="_blank" style="padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem; border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 0.35rem; background-color: #F2A649">
    <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>Metrics
</a>
```

The simple reason was that I accidentally added the type of button to the anchor tag.  It seems that Chrome is smart enough to ignore that attribute while Safari does not.